# In Python, how did I prevent a name from repeating in dataset and sum or average the information of the data given?

Tags: python, pandas, database, datatables

**I am analyzing data found on github reflecting COVID-19 (coronavirus) by Our World in Data on GitHub. The data found will be presented in an organized table format.
**
**Link to data**
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv

**Project Goals:**

List every country in alphabetical order

List the total number of tests conducted by each country

List the total number of vaccinated peoples in each country

List the total number of deaths of each country

Show the average age of death to Covid-19 in each country

**Here is an example of the data**

iso_code,continent,location,date,total_cases,new_cases,new_cases_smoothed,total_deaths,new_deaths,new_deaths_smoothed,total_cases_per_million,new_cases_per_million,new_cases_smoothed_per_million,total_deaths_per_million,new_deaths_per_million,new_deaths_smoothed_per_million,reproduction_rate,icu_patients,icu_patients_per_million,hosp_patients,hosp_patients_per_million,weekly_icu_admissions,weekly_icu_admissions_per_million,weekly_hosp_admissions,weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million,total_tests,new_tests,total_tests_per_thousand,new_tests_per_thousand,new_tests_smoothed,new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand,positive_rate,tests_per_case,tests_units,total_vaccinations,people_vaccinated,people_fully_vaccinated,total_boosters,new_vaccinations,new_vaccinations_smoothed,total_vaccinations_per_hundred,people_vaccinated_per_hundred,people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred,total_boosters_per_hundred,new_vaccinations_smoothed_per_million,new_people_vaccinated_smoothed,new_people_vaccinated_smoothed_per_hundred,stringency_index,population_density,median_age,aged_65_older,aged_70_older,gdp_per_capita,extreme_poverty,cardiovasc_death_rate,diabetes_prevalence,female_smokers,male_smokers,handwashing_facilities,hospital_beds_per_thousand,life_expectancy,human_development_index,population,excess_mortality_cumulative_absolute,excess_mortality_cumulative,excess_mortality,excess_mortality_cumulative_per_million
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-24,5.0,5.0,,,,,0.122,0.122,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,8.33,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.511,41128772.0,,,,
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-25,5.0,0.0,,,,,0.122,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,8.33,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.511,41128772.0,,,,
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-26,5.0,0.0,,,,,0.122,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,8.33,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.511,41128772.0,,,,
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-27,5.0,0.0,,,,,0.122,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,8.33,54.422,18.6,2.581,1.337,1803.987,,597.029,9.59,,,37.746,0.5,64.83,0.511,41128772.0,,,,

**Overall Question:**
How do I sum the countries together so the information does not repeat? I just want the country to display once, and then next to it the sum of the information given from the data for the number of vaccinations displays. Example of the way

**I want the data to display:**

Country Vaccinations

Afghanistan 30235

Albania 15032

Andorra 2352

I have tried to import the data with pandasand sum the data but not quite sure how to get specifically for that one country. I want to write it so I can just display the single country by itself, but I run into the issue of either creating a new table and confuse myself. I am a beginner here and this data set is very large.

Comment: Some Code formatting would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv')

df[['location', 'total_vaccinations']].groupby('location').sum().reset_index()

           location  total_vaccinations
0       Afghanistan        4.013568e+08
1            Africa        1.853572e+11
2           Albania        3.587615e+08
3           Algeria        2.983973e+08
4           Andorra        4.593697e+06
..              ...                 ...
243  Western Sahara        0.000000e+00
244           World        4.857404e+12
245           Yemen        2.126927e+07
246          Zambia        5.435039e+08
247        Zimbabwe        3.211422e+09

[248 rows x 2 columns]
```